# How can I understand if the IOS application goes background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mobile, ios6

In my app I am increasing the brightness of the screen at some part and of course I need to return it back to its value before exiting my app. But I can't catch if the user uses the button and puts the app to the background. Is there any way to understand if the app will work on background so at that point I can change screen brightness to its old value.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement your code by using the following AppDelegate methods, and this is the way to go

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: I have added this to those methods to dim the screen:
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.1];
the problem is it doesn't dim the screen when the button is clicked and starts working on the background but it dims when I reopen it by double clicking to the button and selecting my app. How can I make this function work before app goes back?

Comment: you should put the code of dimming the screen in `applicationWillResignActive` it will dim the screen once your app goes inactive mode or user clicks on Home button. you could bright the screen within `applicationDidBecomeActive` and let me know if it works

Comment: it can print NSLog to my console but it doesn't dim my phone's brightness.

Comment: which version of IOS you are on? if you have IOS6 maybe try to swipe down the notification area... it will work I feel

Comment: IOS 6, when I swipe the notification area it dims but not when I push the button.

Comment: its kind of weird, there is a property in defaults maybe you could try by setting using NSUserDefaults like this `float brightness =0.1;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:brightness forKey:@"sysBright"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:brightness];`

Comment: @mortalkombat If I've understood the issue then I think your issue is that you think you're allowed to set the screen brightness for other apps. iOS apps are sandboxed so I'd be surprised if whatever brightness you select for yourself carries to any other part of the OS.

Comment: if it does not help then I guess it might be a bug and will only work if you use the notification area, or double tap the button, or change to another app.

Comment: on this [link](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/139813?start=25&tstart=0) you could find more info about this bug which was submitted and I think it is not resolved or according to Apple it might not be a bug

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completion I will add that you can do it in your application delegate like others have already said so.
**But** some time it don't make sense to do this in the application delegate, and for those case there is `NSNotification` for that like : `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`.  You will find those notification at the bottom of the [UIApplication class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification).

Answer (score 0):

Implement code in
`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`
and `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`
in your appDelegate class